# How to create a new variable based on changes in another variable in r

Tags: r, variables

I am really an r newbie, but please help me to complete this assignment.

I have the following sample of a dataset on "polityScore", and I need to create a new variable called "politicalChange" that is based on the yearly changes in the first variable, following these conditions:

```
if polityScore in A in year1 + 1 > polityScore in A in year1---> "democratization"
if polityScore in A in year1 + 1 < polityScore in A in year1---> "autocratization"
if polityScore in A in year1 + 1 = polityScore in A in year1---> "no change"
```

the data:

```
country, date, polityScore, politicalChange

A   ,2000   ,5  ,
A   ,2001   ,6  ,
A   ,2002   ,4  ,
A   ,2003   ,5  ,
A   ,2004   ,5  ,
A   ,2005   ,7  ,
B   ,2000   ,5  ,
B   ,2001   ,6  ,
B   ,2002   ,4  ,
B   ,2003   ,5  ,
B   ,2004   ,5  ,
B   ,2005   ,7  ,
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like below. The dplyr package can help with this. First group by country so that the following `if_else` statement is done over each country. In the if_else compares the polityScore with the polityScore from 1 year before and based on that fills in "democratization", "autocratization" or "no change". The first value of the group will be NA.

If you do not want the NA's, but "no change" instead, add `default = first(polityScore)` to the lag function.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  mutate(politicalChange = if_else(polityScore > lag(polityScore), "democratization", 
                                  ifelse(polityScore < lag(polityScore), "autocratization", "no change")))

# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   country [2]
   country  date polityScore politicalChange
   <chr>   <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>          
 1 A        2000           5 NA             
 2 A        2001           6 democratization
 3 A        2002           4 autocratization
 4 A        2003           5 democratization
 5 A        2004           5 no change      
 6 A        2005           7 democratization
 7 B        2000           5 NA             
 8 B        2001           6 democratization
 9 B        2002           4 autocratization
10 B        2003           5 democratization
11 B        2004           5 no change      
12 B        2005           7 democratization
```

For readability of your rules you could also use `case_when` instead of `if_else`. `case_when` also fills in the NA's with the TRUE rule.

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  mutate(politicalChange = case_when(polityScore > lag(polityScore) ~ "democratization", 
                                     polityScore < lag(polityScore) ~ "autocratization",
                                     TRUE ~ "no change"))
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   country [2]
   country  date polityScore politicalChange
   <chr>   <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>          
 1 A        2000           5 no change      
 2 A        2001           6 democratization
 3 A        2002           4 autocratization
.....
```

data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(country = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), date = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005), polityScore = c(5, 
6, 4, 5, 5, 7, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 7), politicalChange = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -12L
), class = "data.frame")
```

P.S.

check [bookdown.org](https://bookdown.org/) for a lot of books on R which can help you further.

Comment: I tried the code on the whole dataset, but I got back the following error message: "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: `false` must be type string, not logical." So what went wrong